# Proving $\phi\wedge\Box\Box\phi\rightarrow\Box(\phi\wedge\Box\Box\phi)$

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I want to know why the formula $\phi\wedge\Box\Box\phi\rightarrow\Box(\phi\wedge\Box\Box\phi)$ is provable in modal logic K5.
Because I think we need more axioms in order to prove the formula.

Also, why does $\phi\vdash_{K5}\phi\wedge\Box\Box\phi$
hold but $\phi\vdash\phi\wedge\Box\phi$
does not hold in K5?

Comment: Why do you think this formula is provable in K5? And for your second question, why do you think the first sequent  is provable in K5?

Comment: I am reading a paper. I put its link below:

https://academic.oup.com/jigpal/advance-article/doi/10.1093/jigpal/jzab036/6515583
Please look at the page 13.

Comment: This is the sort of context you should always include in your questions! When answering a question, it's really helpful to have some background on how the question arose. I recommend you edit your question to include the reference to the paper.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to the paper you linked to in the comments, but I think I have a countermodel demonstrating the failure of the formula that you mentioned in K5.

So, I'm interpreting K5 as the modal logic whose accessibility relations are [constrained to be Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_relation). This means that, if $aRb$ and $aRc$, then it holds that $bRc$ and $cRb$. The $cRb$ conclusion is implied by exchanging the roles of $a$ and $b$, but I like including it for symmetry. If $S$ is an arbitrary relation, let's call the result of adding in all the edges implied by the Euclidean property the Euclidean closure of $S$.

There's another important consequence of being a Euclidean relation pointed out by Alex Kruckman in the comments: if $aRb$, then it holds that $bRb$. In prose, *any world of in-degree at least one is self-accessible*. This is because the world is directly self-accessible, or the world is self-accessible by virtue of being a Euclidean relation, or both.

The original formula $\phi \land \square \square \phi \to \square(\phi \land \square \square \phi)$ is not a tautology in K5.

Here's how to prove it.

Let the set of worlds be $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. Suppose it holds that $0R1, 1R2, 2R3$ and also that $1R1, 2R2, 3R3$. The Euclidean closure of $R$ would add no edges, thus $R$ is Euclidean

Suppose that $A$ holds at $0, 1, 2$ but fails at $3$.

Let's evaluate the truth of the above formula at world $0$ and let $\phi$ be $A$.

Since $A$ holds at $0$ and $2$, $A$ and $\square \square A$ are both true at $0$.

However, $A$ fails at $3$, so at least one of $\{A, \square \square A\}$ fails at $1$.

Thus $\phi \land \square \square \phi \to \square(\phi \land \square \square \phi)$ fails at $0$.

Comment: To have a Euclidean relation, you also need edges $1R1$, $2R2$, and $3R3$. The counterexample still works, but now you need $A$ to hold at $0$, $1$, and $2$ (but not $3$).

Comment: Incidentally, this modified relation also works as a counterexample to the other sequent that the OP claims holds: $A\vdash_{K5} A\land \square\square A$ (evaluated at world $1$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.
Would you pleas take a look at the page 13 of the paper "Unification types in Euclidean modal logics". You can see that in this paper the above formula is provable in K5. Of course, I agree with you that the formula is not provable in K5